# Nginx error that I can't understand at all

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssl, certificate, certbot

When I try to start nginx or apt reload, I get this error:

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-05-17 04:46:59 UTC; 8ms ago
       Docs: man:nginx(8)
    Process: 119844 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 17 04:46:59 instance-20211219-2046 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
May 17 04:46:59 instance-20211219-2046 nginx[119844]: nginx: [emerg] cannot load certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/bitwarden.joscodes.xyz/fullchain.pem": PEM_read_bio_X509_AUX() failed (SSL: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE)
May 17 04:46:59 instance-20211219-2046 nginx[119844]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
May 17 04:46:59 instance-20211219-2046 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
May 17 04:46:59 instance-20211219-2046 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 17 04:46:59 instance-20211219-2046 systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

When I do `certbot certificates` it tells me I have no certs installed, and I have no idea how to resolve this issue.

**System Information:**
Linux instance-20211219-2046 5.13.0-1021-oracle #26~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 7 14:30:17 UTC 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Comment: what is the first line of the pem file?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by completely reloading and wiping NGINX, then regenerating the certs after removing them from the cert bot config :3